# LIBSVM data fomat for categorical data

Tags: java, libsvm, nlp-question-answering

I am doing project on question classification using SVM. Given a question, the system must be able to allocate the class to question. For eg for the question “Where is Tajmahal located?” the task of question classification is to assign label “Location” to this question, since the answer to this question is a named entity of type “Location”. So I know that first i have to provide training dataset from which the model will learn and then testing dataset.
My training dataset contains class, index and value(in terms of question) all categorical.

class       Index      value(question)
DESC        manner     How did serfdom develop in and then leave Russia ?

Likewise i have 6 classes 50 index and 1000 question

SVM takes as input numerical values
For implementing SVM i have downloaded LIBSVM. Libsvm is a libraray for SVM
www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/‎

I dont know how should i convert this data to Libsvm format. Please help